# Storing Html inputs in JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, input

I'm planned to create a sample login page. In which we have to get the basic informations from users in Registration Form and store all the details in Js array.

And the user need to enter their name and password in login form, behind the page we need to check the Details entered in the login form with the data stored in the js array.

Here is my Try:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/JavaScript">
        var users = [];

        function register() {
            users["name"] = [];
            users["password"];
            usr = document.getElementById('usr');
            pwd = document.getElementById('pwd');
            users["name"].push(use);
            users["password"].push(pwd);
        }

        function login() {
            uname = document.getElementById('uname');
            passwd = document.getElementById('passwd');

            if (uname == users["name"]) {
                if (passwd == users["password"]) {
                    alert("Welcome!")

                } else {
                    alert("Wrong Password!");
                }
            } else {
                alert("Wrong Username!");
            }
        }

    </script>
    <title> Portal </title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
    <h3>Register</h3><br>
    Username:
    <input id="usr" type="text"><br>
    Password:
    <input id="pwd" type="password">
    <br>
    <input type="button" onclick="register">
    <br>
    <h3>Login</h3><br>
    Username:
    <input id="uname" type="text"><br>
    Password:
    <input id="passwd" type="text"><br>
    <input type="button" onclick="login()">
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: State your question clearly and format your code, plz.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the parentheses for `onclick=register` + it will be better if you initialize the `users` array like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/JavaScript">
var users={name:[], password:[]};
function register ()
{
usr=document.getElementById('usr');
pwd=document.getElementById('pwd');
users["name"].push(use);
users["password"].push(pwd);
}

function login ()
{
uname=document.getElementById('uname');
passwd=document.getElementById('passwd');

if(uname==users["name"])
{
if(passwd==users["password"])
{
alert("Welcome!")!
}
else
{
alert("Wrong Password!");
}
else
{
alert("Wrong Username!");
}

</script>
<title> Portal </title>
</head>
<body>
<p><h3>Register</h3><br>
Username:
<input id="usr" type="text"><br>
Password:
<input id="pwd" type="password">
<br>
<input type="button" onclick="register()">
<br>
<h3>Login</h3><br>
Username:
<input id="uname" type="text"><br>
Password:
<input id="passwd" type="text"><br>
<input type="button" onclick="login()">
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's working good. But when I tried to show the entered element with     alert(use);

Comment: @Hemath use `console.log(use)` instead for debugging